# OBJECT_DEFINITION (Transact-SQL) - trim trailing and leading empty lines from nvarchar(max) result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The SQL Server function `OBJECT_DEFINITION (Transact-SQL)` returns a
`nvarchar(max)`

For example this SQL:

```
select 
    name,
    --modify_date,
    object_definition(object_id) as SQLText
 from sys.procedures 
where schema_id = 1
```

I am wondering how to work with the `nvarchar(max)` result?
How would I trim trailing and leading empty lines for example?

TRIM doesn't seem to work in this query

Comment: Using the `TRIM` functions maybe? Check the documentation for SQL Server string functions. Of course if you give use a specific goal you are trying to achieve we can help you a lot better - but in any case, the docs are always a good place to start.

Comment: The question is unclear. The result is a string and can be handled using T-SQL's string functions. SQL in general and T-SQL in particular are *very weak* when it comes to string manipulation though. That's simply not SQL's job. If you want to do anything more advanced than trimming or simple substring operations you'll have to use another language on the client

Comment: If you want to keep things in the database, SQL Server 2017 allows you to [call Python scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/tutorials/quickstart-python-create-script?view=sql-server-ver16) on a query result using `sp_execute_external_script`. Python is *very* strong in string manipulation and the distribution that comes with SQL Server is geared towards data science and includes powerful text processing packages, even Natural Language Processing packages.

Comment: Have you actually tried `TRIM`? It seems to work for me https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aee12073ad53b393f7fa8f1cec41be07

Comment: Ah, the `nvarchar(max) and varchar(max) types aren't allowed.` only applies to the `characters` component. Not the `string` part

Comment: SQL Server 2012 gives message 'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name. SQL Server 2017 allows use of trim function fine. 
Trim function does not take the blank line off the bottom of a an nvarchar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The formatting of the `TRIM` documentation is wrong.**

It says:

> **Arguments**
>
> characters Is a literal, variable, or function call of any non-LOB character type (`nvarchar`, `varchar`, `nchar`, or `char`) containing characters that should be removed. `nvarchar(max)` and `varchar(max)` types aren't allowed.
>
> string Is an expression of any character type (`nvarchar`, `varchar`, `nchar`, or `char`) where characters should be removed.

which led you astray in thinking `max` wasn't allowed even on the `string` parameter. It's actually only the `characters` parameter which can't be `max`, [it works fine on `string`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=aee12073ad53b393f7fa8f1cec41be07)

The docs should instead be

> **Arguments**
>
> *characters*
> Is a literal, variable, or function call of any non-LOB character type (`nvarchar`, `varchar`, `nchar`, or `char`) containing characters that should be removed. `nvarchar(max)` and `varchar(max)` types aren't allowed.
>
> *string*
> Is an expression of any character type (`nvarchar`, `varchar`, `nchar`, or `char`) where characters should be removed.

You can make a pull request to change the documentation, [it is open-source](https://github.com/dotnet/docs).

[@DavidBrowne-Microsoft has now created one.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/7870)

---

Note that by default `TRIM` only trims spaces `CHAR(32)`. To trim all whitespace (at least in the Latin-1 characterset) you can use this

```sql
TRIM(CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(32) + CHAR(9) FROM YourValue)
```

Comment: Did you actually try the query with TRIM ? *I* added the edit after verifying there's a problem. I was ready to vote to close when I found that `trim(object_definition(object_id))+ '-'` included the newlines

Comment: `trim` doesn't trim new lines unless you tell it to.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b08750814745686b24fe51dc9f95304

Comment: `datalength(object_definition(object_id)),
datalength(trim(CHAR(13) FROM object_definition(object_id)))` still return 206 and 206. `trim(CHAR(13) FROM object_definition(object_id))+ '-',` is still `create procedure dbo.sp_MScleanupmergepublisher  as      exec sys.sp_MScleanupmergepublisher_internal  -`.

Comment: I tried all these combinations from the start

Comment: clearly there is something wrong with how you are testing it. Maybe you should be trimming `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(32) + CHAR(9)`  to include more white space options. Pasting the definition into comments isn't very useful as they don't preserve things like carriage returns

Comment: @MartinSmith I found the problem. It's a linefeed, not newline. And Python still handles it better than T-SQL

Comment: @MartinSmith ??? I copied the last character from the start and used `UNICODE(..)` to ensure it wasn't a space. I didn't notice it was 10 instead of 13 though, just that it wasn't a `32`. Right now I used `UNICODE(RIGHT(...,1))`

Comment: OK people can you move this off to chat please

Comment: @Charlieface this answer still doesn't help the OP. Can you add that `TRIM(CHAR(10) FROM ...)` would work?

Comment: I created the doc PR: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/pull/7870

Comment: Thanks. How long does that take to get committed to the main site, out of curiosity?

Comment: @Charlieface - I've submitted docs PRs before and the turnaround is usually pretty quick (a couple of days front to back).

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface.  That worked for me ! .. I learnt something new also .. I didn't know I could list extra trim characters like this. Thankyou !